# change ng-model value from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

Basically, I am trying to write a directive for date-picker. In this directive, I am using ng-model's variable to reflect the changed value to parent controller. But I have some problems with it. I do not know how to set an initial value of the ng-model variable. Second I do not get how to update ng-model variable and do validation on it.

I have tried something like this.

```js
angular.module("mainModule.directives").directive('datePicker', function () {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace : false,
        template : '<input ng-model="date" type="text"/>',
        require : 'ngModel',
        scope : {},
        link : function($scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtr) {
            $scope.date = ngModelCtr.$viewValue;

            function fromUser(text) {
                $scope.date = ngModelCtr.$viewValue;
            }

            function toUser(text) {
                ngModelCtr.$setViewValue($scope.date);
            }

            ngModelCtr.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            ngModelCtr.$formatters.push(toUser);
        }
    };

    return  directive;
});
```

```html
<date-picker ng-model="modelDate"></date-picker>
```

Comment: after i changed date variable of directive it should reflect in ng-models variable i.e. modelDate and also set validation parameters from directive

Comment: You need to "implement" `ngModel.$render()` to transfer the model value to the view. And then somehow (depends on the exact implementation of the directive) you have to call `ngModel.$setViewValue(value)` to update the model from the UI. See the example at the bottom of the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsers and formatters work with the existing value and should return the parsed or formatted result I think.  You can set `ngModelController.$render` to a function that will be called when the value changes, and then use `ngModelController.$setViewValue` to update the value when you want.  Here's a fiddle showing using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to only update the underlying model if a valid date is entered ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/wtpd0jx0/1)):

```
link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$render = function() {
        scope.date = moment(ctrl.$viewValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    };
    scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // only update if it is a valid date string
        var m = moment(newValue);
        if (m.isValid()) {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(m);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to render the viewValue to DOM by

```
ngModelController.$render()
```